# Pip not following my install-option (windows), can't use installed zlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, zlib

I'm trying to download the indicoio library on my Windows computer with Python 3.6, and I type in:

```
pip install indicoio
```

And it gives me this giant stack trace:

```
Collecting indicoio
  Using cached IndicoIo-1.0.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Single threaded build for windows
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 248, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 278, in run
        return func()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 246, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\misin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-m05jeejo\Pillow-3.4.2\setup.py", line 753, in <module>
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
        cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
        self.run_command(cmdname)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
        self.build()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\misin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-m05jeejo\Pillow-3.4.2\setup.py", line 521, in build_extensions
    ValueError: zlib is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-zlib, aborting

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\misin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-p80hrlo4\indicoio\setup.py", line 52, in <module>
        "futures >= 3.0.0"
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 665, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 695, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 876, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1115, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1101, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 251, in run_setup
        raise
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 169, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 144, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 248, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 278, in run
        return func()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 246, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\misin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-m05jeejo\Pillow-3.4.2\setup.py", line 753, in <module>
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
        cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
        self.run_command(cmdname)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
        self.build()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\misin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\misin\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-m05jeejo\Pillow-3.4.2\setup.py", line 521, in build_extensions
    ValueError: zlib is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-zlib, aborting

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\misin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-p80hrlo4\indicoio\
```

So I instead typed

```
pip install --install-option="disable-zlib" indicoio
```

But it gives the same error! I even tried doing --global-option and it didn't work. For the record, I get this error with Pillow too. I even tried downloading [zlib for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm) and adding it to my path, but that didn't seem to do the trick :(

Thank you!

Comment: Try using `--install-option="--disable-zlib"` or `--global-option="--disable-zlib"` (note the leading `--`)

Comment: @jmd_dk both fail for me

Comment: Does `pip` work at all? If you have installed bare Python, you might want to consider installing an entire Python *distribution* instead, which comes with both zlib and pip and a whole lot of other extras. Check out e.g. Anaconda: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: @jmd_dk pip works for me for downloading other things.